# Floatable in HTML more then one all labels are Floating

Tags: html, typescript, scss-lint

I am trying to create custom Float label in Ionic but once field it woks . More then once Field all labels are floating when we click on any input Pls help me this

This is my HTML code:

> **Input.htmls**
>
> ```
>      <div class="form-field">
>       <label [ngClass]="focused ? 'label-focused' : ''">Hellow</label>
>     <input type="text" (focus)="focused = true" (blur)="onBlur($event)" />
>   </div>
> ```

This is my SCSS code:

> **Input.scss**
>
> ```
>   .form-field {
>   position: relative;
>   margin-bottom: 1rem;
>   height: 50px;
>
>   label {
>     position: absolute;
>     left: 1rem;
>     top: 1rem;
>     padding: 0 0.25rem;
>     color: #61686f;
>     font-size: 15px;
>     transition: 0.3s;
>     font-family: "Montserrat";
>   }
>
>   input {
>     position: absolute;
>     top: 0;
>     left: 0;
>     height: 100%;
>     width: 100%;
>     font-size: 15px;
>     border: 2px solid #e7ebee;
>     border-radius: 10px;
>     outline: none;
>     padding: 1rem;
>     background: none;
>     z-index: 1;
>     color: #171c25;
>     font-family: "Montserrat";
>   }
>
>   input:focus {
>     border-color: #fa578e;
>   }
>
>   .label-focused {
>     top: -0.4rem;
>     left: 0.8rem;
>     font-size: 14px;
>     font-weight: 600;
>     background-color: #fff;
>     z-index: 10;
>   }
> }
> ```

> This is my component typescript code:
> Input.ts
>
> ```
> onBlur(event: any) {
> const value = event.target.value;
>
> if (!value) {
>   this.focused = false;
> }   }
> ```

floting lable image [image]

Comment: Please make the question clearer. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve here...or what the problem is.

Comment: You can put your code in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen) or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to help us understand what you are trying to do. Your sentences are very broken english. Take your time to explain what you want to do and what is not working.